# Unable to click on the drop down link

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to click on the Drop Down link using selenium web driver. When i search for example they all show by using select, which does not work for me.

I need to click on the dropdown button i.e "dd_txt ng-binding" and choose atleast one value

```
<div class="pull-right cpa_dropdown cpa_col">
<div class="dropdown">
<span class="dropdown_ul_text" data-toggle="dropdown" style="background-color: transparent;">
<span class="dd_txt ng-binding">CCC</span>
<span class="arrrow_img"/>
</span>
```

The following is the Soln for this..

```
public void <methodname>(int list) {
        List<WebElement> li = wb.findElements(By.className("<Classname>"));
        for (int i = 0; i < li.size(); i++) {
            li.get(i).getText();
            if (i == 3) {
                li.get(i).click();
                List<WebElement> li1 = wb.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='<id>']/li"));
                for (int j = 0; j < li1.size(); j++) {
                    String x = li1.get(j).getText();
                    if (j == 1) {
                        li1.get(j).click();
                        System.out.println(x);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have no select element in the markup you provided. So you have to to webElement.click() instead.

Comment: can you add the full code for the dropdown ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the website? If not, can you find from your devs. what framework they are using for this widget?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a dropdown, this is some fancy AJAX that *looks* like a dropdown. You need to use discrete clicks. Start with something like the following, but you will need to experiment (or post a link to your site) to get it to work the way you need.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("dd_txt")).click();
```

Comment: Well, we could be guessing until our fingers fall off, or you could just post some more code and any errors. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please edit your original post with the new code. SO is not a discussion forum, so do not worry about thread history. It is acceptable and advised to keep editing your original question to make it as clear as possible, so that people can help you out.

Comment: As the same Class names where used in multiple places this issue occurred.  If you guys have any suggestion to enhance this code let me know.. Sorry for late response.